# ASP.NET a SQL Server stored procedure with return

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I want to erase the guid `@value` from the database and retrieve the return value from my stored procedure

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.verifGuids
@value char(36),
@message char(1)Output
AS
Begin

DECLARE @SelectValue char(36)

select @SelectValue = value FROM guids WHERE @value=value; 

If @value=@SelectValue 
BEGIN
DELETE value FROM guids WHERE @value=value ;
SET @message = 0
END
Else 
BEGIN
Set @message = 1
END

Return @message
END
```

This is my vb.code in asp.net

```
 Dim guids As String = (Request.QueryString("ID"))
        'stored procedure get Guid
        Dim intRowsAff As Integer
        Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BecsEtMuseauxSQL").ConnectionString
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("verifGuids", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Char, 36).Value = guids
        Dim returnvalue As New SqlParameter("@message", SqlDbType.Char, 1)
        returnvalue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        cmd.Parameters.Add(returnvalue)

        Try
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            intRowsAff = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim retour As String = (cmd.Parameters("@message").Value.ToString())
            If retour = 0 Then

                InformationLabel.Text = "Votre compte à été vérifier vous pouver vous connecter sur le site"
            Else

                InformationLabel.Text = "Votre compte n'est pas aprouvé veuiller vérifier dans vos mail le message de confirmation de votre compte "
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            InformationLabel.Text = ex.Message & ex.Source & intRowsAff '& " record(s) inserted"
        End Try


        cmd.Connection.Close()

    End If
```

I catch an error

> object name 'value' not valid..Net SqlClient Data Provider0

I don't understand what I doing wrong...

This is in Vb.net...

Thanks

Comment: On **which line** do you get that error?? Maybe your query string parameter doesn't exist / is empty?? The code looks fine as far as I can tell.....

Comment: intRowsAff = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an error in your stored procedure code:

```
select @SelectValue = value FROM guids WHERE @value=value;
```

This is wrong - it should be

```
SELECT @SelectValue = value FROM guids WHERE value = @value
```

The same here:

```
DELETE value FROM guids WHERE @value=value ;
```

You must compare the **column** (`value`) to the parameter passed in (`@value`) and not the other way around! So change this to:

```
DELETE FROM guids WHERE value = @value
```

and you should be fine

Your stored proc is much too complicated.... you could simplify it to be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.verifGuids
    @value char(36),
    @message char(1) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- this will *already* delete only if the "value" column matches your "@value"
    -- parameter - there's really no need to first do a SELECT on that table to 
    -- verify that!
    DELETE FROM dbo.guids WHERE value = @value;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       SET @message = 0  -- if you deleted anything - the set @message to "0"
    ELSE
       SET @message = 1

    RETURN @message
END
```

Comment: I change it to the column  named value to valueGuid and it still object name 'valueGuid ' not valid..Net SqlClient Data Provider0 on execute cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use as Out Parameter for your return value. you can refer this site
[Parameter Directions](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/02/19/examples-of-using-system-data-parameterdirection-with-sql-server.aspx), and also you check the [MSDN Documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx)

Comment: The OP **does have** an `OUTPUT` parameter in his stored proc, and he also sets it up correctly (as far as I can see) in his VB.NET code....

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your delete statement in the stored proc to:

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE code=@valueGuid
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ParameterDirection.Output` to `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`

Comment: That's not really going to change anything and certainly not going to solve the issue the OP is having..... and he **does have** an `OUTPUT` parameter which he can read out. This doesn't help at all, sorry.